# How to clean up related files from deleted apps?

Tags: applications, uninstallation

[AppCleaner](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/25276/appcleaner) will delete related files from the Mac when an application is dragged to the trash. How does one clean up remains of uninstalled apps on Android?

Comment: If you delete the app from the device, it will delete all associated files except those on the sd card. Ihe android system should keep everything pretty clean for you.

Comment: Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#what-about-other-android-related-questions) for details). I took the freedom to re-phrase your question, so it no longer falls into this category :)

Comment: Always glad to help :) @John while that is generally true, there are exceptions. See my answer below. One very specific exception would be using `pm uninstall -k`, which would uninstall the app but keep its data. Another (more common) exception are app data saved to sdcard. Plus there might be rare cases where a clean uninstall failed or crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [SD Maid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm). This app requires root for full functionality. This "cleaning made" takes care for multiple remains: a "corpse finder" checks for what an uninstalled app might have left, the "system cleaner" scans the devices known directories with unnecessary files. You can check for the biggest files on your device to free up space, and even optimize and shrink bloated databases to speed up access and free space.

The app includes a file manager, and also allows you to search for files.

[image: SDMaid Corpse Finder] [image: SDMaid System Cleaner]
<sup>*SD MAID* Corpse Finder and System Cleaner (source: Google Play; click images for larger variant)</sup>

**Edit:** For more details and discussion, you might want to visit [the app's thread at XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1013063) :)